# Making a zip code search program for a Python class project

Tags: python, arrays, csv

I've been working on a python program for a class that takes a file, Zipcodes.txt, reads it into an array. It does that so a user can enter their zipcode and get the city and state it belongs to.

The Zipcodes.txt files if formatted like this, a CSV set-up:

```
90401,SANTA MONICA,CA <br>
90023,LOS ANGELES,CA<br>
```

etc...

This the code I have so far:

```
def main():
    # Trying this order of calling the functions
    readFile()
    readRecord()
    promptUser()
    printRecord()

def readFile():
    # Tried following the example files that came with the Powerpoint
    # Do I need this? What changes?
    infile = open("zipcodes.txt","rb")
    eof, zipRecord = readRecord(infile)
    while not eof:
        printRecord(infile)
        eof, zipRecord = readRecord(zipRecord)
   infile.close()

def promptUser():  
    zipQuery = input("Enter a zip code to find (Press Enter key alone to stop): ")

def readRecord(infile):    
    zipSplit = infile.split(',')
    zipCode = infile[0]
    city = infile[1]
    state = infile[2]

def printRecord():
    # Print statement is like this for testing
    print(city + state)

main()
```

The results are supposed to look like this:

```
Enter a zip code to find (Press Enter key alone to stop): 90401
The city is SANTA MONICA and the state is CA.
```

I've only been in this class for 8 weeks and I am a complete newbie to programming, but I've been able to figure out everything put before me so far.
I'm spinning wheels on this one.

Comment: Is there a \n after CA in the text ?

Comment: I don't see a question.

Comment: The indentations aren't correct, can you tidy them up so we can see a runnable program?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately describe the problem.  Show the output you have and the output you got.  Cut the problem down to only the failing part of the code.  Wherever possible before teh problem point, replace your program's manipulations with direct assignments.

Comment: Notice how `readFile` has a while loop that does the processing? If you do the work in readfile, you shouldn't call the functions again in main. Is there any reason why you have several functions? I would implement the whole thing in one block of code.

Comment: Does it have to be stored in array or can we use any module we want?

Comment: Improved formatting

Answer (score 0):

Without test and error handling:

```
import csv
zip_info_dct = {}
with open('zipcodes.txt"', 'rb') as csvfile:
     spamreader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=' ', quotechar='|')
     for row in spamreader:
       zip_code = row[0]
       city = row[1]
       state = row[2]
       zip_info_dct [zip_code] = (city, state)
zip_query = input("Enter a zip code to find (Press Enter key alone to stop): ")
if zip_query in zip_info_dct : 
    info = zip_info_dct [zip_query]
    print "The city is %s and the state is %s" % (info [0], info [1])
```

The pythonic way to read a text-file is :

```
f = open('zipcodes.txt', 'rt')
for line in f :
    print line
f.close ()
```

see https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html